# Getting a matrix of the similarity values between all elements in word2vec

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, word2vec

I am using code based on the [TensorFlow word2vec tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec).

I would like to write a textfile that contains a matrix of similarity values between each of the elements of the dataset AND their corresponding word-labels.

I think 'sim' stores these similarity values:

```
 sim = similarity.eval()
```

as:

```
# Compute the cosine similarity between minibatch examples and all embeddings.
  norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(embeddings), 1, keep_dims=True))
  normalized_embeddings = embeddings / norm
  valid_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(
      normalized_embeddings, valid_dataset)
  similarity = tf.matmul(
      valid_embeddings, normalized_embeddings, transpose_b=True)
```

sim is basically a unique_data_length x unique_data_length object that displays all of the similarity values. Great.

I want to also get the labels for each similarity value.

e.g. if I get:

```
sim[i][j]
```

**Then what is i and what is j. Can I just do: reverse_dictionary[i] to get it's real value? Is it really stored in order that way?**

In the tutorial, they get the closes X words in a validation set:

```
  sim = similarity.eval()
  for i in xrange(valid_size):
    valid_word = reverse_dictionary[valid_examples[i]]
    top_k = 8  # number of nearest neighbors
    nearest = (-sim[i, :]).argsort()[1:top_k + 1]
    log_str = "Nearest to %s:" % valid_word
    for k in xrange(top_k):
      close_word = reverse_dictionary[nearest[k]]
      log_str = "%s %s," % (log_str, close_word)
    print(log_str)
```

The line that really confuses me here is:

```
nearest = (-sim[i, :]).argsort()[1:top_k + 1]
```

Why does that output the encoded values instead of the similarity values?

Answer (score 0):

According to the best of my knowledge, sim position i (and j) represents the i't element, that can be identified by reverse_dictionary[i].